# LDAP proxy to addd jpegPhoto to results

Tags: proxy, ldap, squid, openldap

I want to build or implement some sort of LDAP proxy that will intercept the LDAP response from our corporate server and tack on a jpegPhoto to each entry which will load the persons image from our intranet (i.e. http://intranet.biz/userPhoto.php?email=johnDoe@domain.com).

My first thought is to setup a Squid proxy with a rewrite filter. The OpenLDAP man pages also seems to mention that it can act as a proxy (perhaps using slapo-rwm to add jpegPhoto?). I'm not very familiar with OpenLDAP and I'm not sure how to implement this.

What's the best solution? Any examples?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look into openldap's overlays combined with the proxy backends they offer. The 'translucent' overlay might be an appropriate starting point.

Comment: With that solution at least the images do not have to be stored in the company ldap server. They still need to be in the proxy ldap server. A simple perl script can could automatically fetch and insert them on a regular basis.

Answer (score -2):

Very difficult. You will have to write something that can completely parse an LDAP response and add the required attributes to it. There are various LDAP APIs available that can do that for you but it will be a slog. Have you considered bulk-moving the jpegs *into* the LDAP database?

Comment: There exist proxy solutions for ldap and the OP even mentions them.

Comment: @ypnos: of course. OpenLDAP can even proxy for itself. But do there exist proxy solutions for LDAP that will alter the response as he describes?

Comment: Well, you don't have to re-implement whole ldap query processing, instead just use a proxy and then see how you can feed that one.

Comment: @ypnos: I said nothing about query processing so this is entirely irrelevant. I said you have to parse the response enough to be able to add the attribute to it. The statement remains true, and the downvote remains poorly motivated.

Comment: Your claim "You will have to write something that can completely parse an LDAP response" is an inaccurate absolute statement and therefore *not helpful*. You can use existing software that alters the responses for you. There would not be a downvote for "One solution is to completely parse an LDAP response".

Comment: @ypnos: 'There are various LDAP APIs available that can do that for you' is not helpful, but 'You can use existing software' is helpful? Please explain the difference to me.

Comment: Again, my only concern with your answer is that you claim it can *only* be done your (hard) way.